# How to? re-install desktop/gui on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: login

I had an old 16.04 system which was having issues but was set for retirement.  I needed to get it working well enough to log in and get some data from two graphical applications.

I tried upgrading to 18.04 which was a big struggle (involving purging and re-installing Perl and Pythong(3?)).  Could not get to a login screen.

Upgraded again to 20.04 (which went very smoothly) but still no graphical login screen (just the white-red dots screen).  In 20.04 I was being prompted for credentials for a network share so I know fstab was being parsed.

Upgraded again to 22.04 (which also went smoothly).  No longer parsing fstab and still no login screen.

I can console in and I can ssh in so I can make changes.  I tried suggestions around the login loop issue and around logging into blank screens, but none of that had any noticable impact.

> I looked at the output for both `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal` and `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` but
> those involve adding more than 300 packages, so that seems the wrong
> route entirely.

I have now run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal` and now show the current version of the waiting screen, but the system still fails to get a graphical login screen.

Suggestions?

Comment: Your command doesn't install anything on my desktop system, which means it's fine and you should do it.

Comment: Hmmm... confirmed on my lappy too.  Well, here's mud in your eye...

Comment: I am now getting the new waiting screen (the spinning not-quite-arrows), so... progress?  Still no login screen.

Comment: Retrieving data also be done using a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment.

Comment: @user535733 -- I need to run a couple of applications in their current state on that system to extract data from those applications directly (data that is not text accessible otherwise).

Comment: @JamesIsIn Try starting Ubuntu in recovery mode

Comment: If I hit Shift-Esc I see three lines on the console:  1) Starting Message of the Day... 2) [ OK ] Finished Message of the Day.  3) [*** ] A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (3h 12 min 3s / no limit) .  That might be a useful clue.

Comment: After a reboot I was able to access RM.  I started networking, made sure Grub was up to date, and ran dpkg to repair anything missing.  Returning to the normal boot sequence dropped me at a console login.  I was able to login in as per usual.  Rebooted again.  Same situation:  graphical waiting page but no login page.

Answer (score 0):

First try whether reinstalling plymouth may restore a graphical login screen:

```
sudo apt purge plymouth
sudo apt install plymouth
```

If that did not work, **the better advice may be to start afresh**: wipe all that is there, and do a fresh install. Your current system may have become a Frankenstein system by now. Reinstalling will be the fastest and by far the cleanest solution.

Otherwise, since you got the system this far to boot a basic terminal based linux system, you could

- Remove most of the graphical packages and reinstall. A `sudo apt remove --purge xserver-xorg plymouth` will probably be more than enough to remove anything related to a graphical desktop. Still run a `sudo apt autoremove` afterwards. Then install a minimal `ubuntu-desktop`

or

- Boot from a live CD of Ubuntu 22.04 and perform a reinstall without erasing the existing partitions. Also that will preserve user data and configuration.

Comment: Is xserver-org the correct package name?  E: Unable to locate package xserver-org  (Purging and reinstalling Plymouth itself now leads me to a console login with no GUI splash.)

Comment: I corrected the name

Comment: Thanks.  Now that I have done this reboots briefly show the spinning splash screen and then I am dropped to a console login.  Do I need to do something special to tell the system to start X (automatically)?

Comment: (Running startx enters Gnome on X rather than Ubuntu so followers should be aware of this distinction.)

Comment: A reinstall would have taken you an hour. If that fails, attempt installation of older versions. If these fail, expect possible hardware issues with that computer.

Comment: I know the hardware is good and this issue persisted across two machines when I moved the drive.  I'll try the CD re-install.

Comment: The live version makes no offer to in-place re-install.  Not clear about using the "somehting else" to get there.  I would need to know how to utilze (or protect) each existing partition.

Comment: A re-install is done through "something else", so you must know your partitions indeed.